# Unknown types found, no types for DepartmentDetails

Tags: substrate, polkadot

I am trying to use struct in substrate

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Default, Clone, Encode, Decode, RuntimeDebug)]
pub struct DepartmentDetails {
    pub name: Vec<u8>,
    pub location: Vec<u8>,
    pub details: Vec<u8>,
    pub departmentid: u128,
}
```

In decl_stroage

```
Department get(fn department_name): map hasher(blake2_128_concat) u128 => DepartmentDetails;
```

Though node runs successfully without error, it give error with polkadotjs app, saying:
Unknown types found, no types for DepartmentDetails

https://substrate.dev/recipes/structs.html

Comment: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/FAQ#i-am-getting-a-unknown-types-found-no-types-for--error

Comment: You need to add a type definition in `Settings > Developer` for your custom type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polkadot-js can only construct and display types that it understands.
See the FAQ [here](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/FAQ#i-am-getting-a-unknown-types-found-no-types-for--error).

For development you can add custom type descriptions in the `Settings > Developer` tab.

For production you can add type descriptions to your polkadot-js based UI via extending the types as described [here](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/types.extend/).